# Merge Hash (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ, Int Raku, how to merge, combine two hashes?

Say:

```
my %a = 1 => 2;
my %b = 3 => 4, 5 => 6
```

How to get `%c = 1 => 2, 3 => 4, 5 => 6` ?

Comment: What do you want to do with repeat keys (if any)?

Comment: @vonbrand, overwrite them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip) [prefix |](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#prefix_|)
2. Use [append](https://docs.raku.org/type/Hash#method_append) Hash method
3. Use [infix , operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_,)

Assuming:

```
my %a = 1 => 'a', 3 => 4;
my %b = 1 => 'b', 5 => 6;
```

```
say %(|%a, |%b);  # {1 => b, 3 => 4, 5 => 6}
say %().append(%a).append(%b);  # {1 => [a b], 3 => 4, 5 => 6}
my %c = %a, %b; say(%c);  # {1 => b, 3 => 4, 5 => 6}
```

Comment: `say %().append(%a).append(%b);` is dodgy in a couple ways. First, in a very slight way; if you write `use v6.c; 'a' ~~ /a/;` at the start of your program/module or use an old Rakudo that only supports `6.c` your code will break due to `%()` having a different meaning in `6.c`. Much more importantly, in any version, if `%a` and `%b` share at least one key then you'll get a different result than from `say %(|%a, |%b);`. See the `append` doc you linked for details.

Comment: `my %c = %a,%b` with the caveats that the keys in `%b` will be leading.

Comment: I update my answer with your comments. Thank you both.